# Optimal/Stable/...? discretization of second (higher) order ODEs

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-equations, na.numerical-analysis

I will phrase the question only for second order ODE's although the same question might come up for higher orders.

ODEs of the form

$$
f(t, x,\dot{x}) = \ddot{x}
$$

are usually converted to first order ODEs with the trick $y=(x,\dot{x})$ which then results in an equivalent formulation

$$
g(t, y) = \begin{pmatrix}
y_2 \\
f(t, y)
\end{pmatrix}
=\dot{y}
$$

But while discretizations of first order ODE's are well studied with arbitrary convergence order being achieved by the family of Runge Kutta methods, I am not aware of any theory on higher order ODE discretizations. And I believe that the conversion to first order ODE's probably sacrifices a lot of potential (I will explain this belief in my motivation).

#### Motivation

We will be looking at gradient decent with momentum on a loss function $L$. Instead of setting the velocity of the decent equal to the steepest decent

$$
\dot{x} = -\nabla L(x)
$$

we instead want to set the acceleration to be equal to the steepest decent and add some decelerating force ("friction") proportional to the current velocity

$$
\ddot{x} = -\nabla L(x) - \alpha\dot{x}
$$

The trick above and euler discretization yields

$$
y^{n+1} = y^n + \eta
\begin{pmatrix}
y^n_2 \\
-\nabla L(y^n_1) - \alpha y^n_2
\end{pmatrix}
$$

with a bit of reparametrization ($h=\eta^2$, $x=y_1$, $m=y_2/\eta$, $\beta=1-\eta\alpha$) this (almost) results in the well known heavy ball (momentum) method

$$
\begin{aligned}
x^{(n)} &= x^{(n-1)} + hm^{(\color{red}{n-1})}\\
m^{(n)} &= \beta m^{(n-1)} - \nabla L(x^{(n-1)})
\end{aligned}
$$

In reality (e.g. https://distill.pub/2017/momentum/) people use the current momentum $m^{(n)}$ for the position update. Now taking the learning rate to zero ($h\to 0$), this will likely result in the same ODE. But in the discrete case it makes a difference.

Substituting in $m^{(n-1)}$ into the first equation we would get

$$
x^{(n)} = x^{(n-1)} + h(\beta m^{(n-1)} - \nabla L(x^{(n-2)})
$$
which means we are not using the gradient information from our previous position $x^{(n-1)}$ to calculate the current position $x^{(n)}$ but the one before that. This means our optimization algorithm will overshoot when a change in gradient occurs.

[Nesterov's momentum](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/191727/265966) goes one step further and first applies the current momentum and only then calculates the gradient

$$
x^{(n)} = \underbrace{x^{(n-1)} + h\beta m^{(n)}}_{\text{"momentum move"}} -\nabla L(x^{(n-1)} + h\beta m^{(n)})
$$

This is argued to perform even better (cf. https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/368179/265966)

> Whatever jump comes first, my Momentum Jump would be the same.
> So I should consider the situation as if I have already made my Momentum Jump, and I am about to make my Slope Jump.

#### Concluding Thoughts

Now all these slight heuristic modifications make intuitive sense. But I wonder if there is some theory to put this on a solid foundation and maybe even find an "optimal" discretization.

What I find remarkable is, that higher order methods (like the [Heun's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heun%27s_method)) also do some form of look ahead:

$$
x^{(k+1)} = x^{(k)} + \tfrac12 h \big[f(x^{(k)}) + f\big(\underbrace{x^{(k)} + hf(x^{(k)})}_{\text{"look ahead"}}\big)\big]
$$

In our second order ODE we just did a *skewed* lookahead, where we used a newer momentum to update our position. So higher order ODE discretization might have to somehow incorporate that.

Comment: Optimal w.r.t what criteria ?

Comment: @Piyush I am not sure myself - this is really an open ended question for discussion. In the motivating example one could ask for optimal convergence rates for certain classes of loss functions. In the general case maybe optimal in the sense that the difference between the real ode and the discretization stays smaller than epsilon for as large as possible step sizes. But you are welcome to point out other measures

Comment: There is theory on second-order ODE discretizations, and it is in the textbooks.

Comment: See for instance section II.14 of of Hairer vol. 1.

Comment: @DavidKetcheson thank you for the reference - I'll be reading that. Although the first thing that is done in this chapter is the trick I mentioned